# Accessing inner child selector from unique parent in coffeescript/selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am writing a test in selenium using coffeescript.js and chai frameworks to select an inner child element where the parent has a unique class name.

The children elements are reused through the application and are not unique, so I need the parent's name to be used as a unique locator

[image: example]

`portals-client__portals` is the parent element I want to use to reference `toggles__name`

```
  "created_portal_in_super": {
    "xpath": "//span[contains(@class,'toggles__name')]"
  }
```

what is the correct way of nesting this?

I know for tables, something like `tbody > tr > td` can be used but I am not sure how to make this work in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class, "portals-client__portals")]//span[@class="toggles__name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Css selector:

```
.portals-client__portals span.toggles__name
```